# Why include_graphics in my child Rmd not working?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have 2 files: main and child. In child I use `include_graphics` from `knitr`.

Files are in this directories:

`./Project/book/Main.Rmd`

`./Project/sections/sec1/sec1.Rmd` (child)

And png that i generate are in:

`./Project/sections/sec1/figure/example.png`

I tried commented paths in `include_graphics`.

Main.Rmd

````
```{r}
require(tidyverse)
require(knitr)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE, 
  warning = FALSE,
  message = FALSE
)    
```

```{r, child = '../sections/sec1/sec1.Rmd'}   
```
````

Sec1.Rmd

````
```{r}
# files <- list.files("figure", full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".png")
# files <- paste("./", list.files("figure", full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".png"), sep = "")
files <- paste(getwd(), list.files("figure", full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".png"), sep = "/")


include_graphics(path = files)
```
````

There are no error, png is just icon of bad load image.

Only time when png was in document was when i copy folder `figure` to directory: `./Project/book/...`. But it's not soluction for me (i have multiple child files where I use include_graphics, and some of them include multiple png)

Comment: Have you tried using figure paths relative to the main document?

Comment: I'm using getwd(), with paste(), so when i print `files` i get good path to figures: `.../Project/sections/sec1/figure/...`. Even when i add line `print(files)` above include_graphics.